# How to move back and forth between two specific instances of two view controllers without having to pass data each time

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation, segue, viewcontroller

I have a view controller A and from there I segue (show) to a view controller B. While on B i have a button that I want to bring me back to A. And a button on A that I want to bring me back to B. However, after the initial segue that creates the instance of B I want to continue to use the very same instance. (Not dismiss it and pass in data during a segue to recreate it) I am looking for something that maybe just hides the view to show A below it and then be able to reshow the view when I want to work on B again.

I have tried in B using self.view.isHidden = true and then in A when I am done and want to go back to B using myInstanceOfB.view.isHidden = false. However when I hide the view the screen just goes black

Comment: You might use paging for this.